# How edit wordpress plugin code from openshift?

Tags: wordpress, openshift

I started a Wordpress web site in Openshift and now I have a problem with a plugin and I want edit the code... but the repository have any code. What can I do?

Where is the core code? Where is the folder of uploads?

In the repository I have this folders:

- action_hooks
- config
- cron
- languages
- plug-ins
- themes

And all is empyt, less the config, in there have the wp-config and .htaccess

How can I get the code of wordpresss, code of plug-ins and the uploads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for @tyasird by said about SFTP.

What I did for get the code of plug-ins:

- Get putty and import my ssh key
- Convert the key for the putty format and save
- Open Filezilla and config the SFTP to use the putty's generated key and use my id to login
- I donwload the folder **/var/lib/openshift/[MY-ID]/app-root/data**

And in the folder data have the folder plugins with the code of plug-ins and the folder uploads with the images uploads by year and moth.

Now I can to edit the code of plug-ins.

Answer (score 0):

your plugins and themes in .openshift directory

**/var/lib/openshift/[YOUR-ID]/app-root/runtime/repo/.openshift**

to access here try this, Using SFTP with OpenShift: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g6G-Pkl_fzs

Comment: thanks, I did not know the SFTP. I'm using the https://blog.openshift.com/using-filezilla-and-sftp-on-windows-with-openshift/ method and not Works. Any tips?

Comment: I get the folder /app-root/runtime/repo/.openshift and this folder have the same things I said before... only folders empyts